# How to show Apache Tomcat 7.0 console window?

Tags: tomcat7

Where can I find or how can i show the console window of Tomcat 7.0?

I have installed it successfully and tested it. But, I want to see its console for output information, errors, etc.

I have found on some forum that I need to run the startup.bat (that was for Tomcat 4.0), but I am using Tomcat 7 and I don't see any startup.bat in its directory, is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

tail -f $CATALINA_BASE/logs/catalina.out

Answer (score 2):

I have Tomcat 7 installed on Windows Server 2008. Be sure to look in the [tomcat-install-dir]/bin directory for the start.bat file.

start.bat will open a console window and show up-to-the-second server logs (also known as 'tail').

Answer (score 0):

On apache tomcat version 7,there is a folder called bin ,open it and then open tomcat7 application .It will show console window.